# how to get host url in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am using model reveal feature with ajax call. one application has more than one domain i tried `request.host` but this doesn't worked as expected. how can i get host with url as shown below-

```
<div class="full reveal" id="<%= site_model_id %>" data-reveal data-ajax-url="http://0.0.0.0:3000/project_sites/<%= project_site.id %>/attendances/">

 <button class="close-button" data-close aria-label="Close modal" type="button">
  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

what i tried as url

```
data-ajax-url="#{request.host}/project_sites/<%= project_site.id %>/attendances/"
```

but this opens only root_page not target page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

posted solution that worked for me:

```
<% domain = request.base_url %>
  <div class="full reveal" id="<%= site_modal_id%>" data-reveal data-ajax-url="<%= domain %>/project_sites/<%= project_site.id %>/attendances/">
  <button class="close-button" data-close aria-label="Close modal" type="button">
  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
</div>
```